# add xpath transformation to root document

Tags: xpath, xmlsec, xades4j

In xades4j, in case of multiple enveloping signature i will have my signed document with, at the end, more *Signature* elements, but i need to tell to each reference to signed document (URI="") that he must not refers to other *Signature* element that represent other Signature, i need so to add this transformation

```
<ds:Reference URI="">
    <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2">
            <dsig-xpath:XPath Filter="subtract">/descendant::ds:Signature</dsig-xpath:XPath>   
        </ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms> 
....
```

Telling that it must not to consider ds:Signature element for signature production.
How xades4j permit the use of this kind of transformation?

Thanks

Michele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the transforms when defining the `DataObjectReference`. Check the examples on the [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/xades4j/wiki/DefiningSignedResources#Transforms) and the [`XPath2FilterTransform` class documentation](http://xades4j.googlecode.com/svn/release/1.3.0/javadoc/reference/xades4j/algorithms/XPath2FilterTransform.html).